# what is line in the htaccess doing?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was having problems with an img folder having a 403 forbidden and come to find out the issue was caused by this line....what is this doing

```
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|exe|zip)$ - [F,NC]
```

and why would it cause a 403 forbidden on a /something/img folder that had images

Answer (score 2):

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html
F = forbidden, forces 403 errors on all URLs ending with one of these extensions.
NC = no case (ie. also works on .GIF for example.

Answer (score 2):

`RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|exe|zip)$` Matches any file names containing any number of characters followed by a period and one of those file extionsions.

`-` Tells mod_rewrite to keep the URL untouched; a technicality emplofed when showing a 403 forbidden page.

`[F,NC]` F=Forbidden, NC=No case; a case-insensitive match.

Most likely this rule follows (or is supposed to follow) one or more `RewriteCond`s, which are conditions under which the RewriteRule will trigger. The intention of the rule was probably to block images and other files from being [hotlinked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking). Without the `RewriteCond`, images will always be blocked.

A well designed rule for preventing hotlinking will look something like this:

```
# Only apply the rule if the referrer isn't empty...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
# ... and doesn't match your site.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !\.?mysite.com/$
# Also, only apply the rule for the specified file types.
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|exe|zip)$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: That rule is also known as BreakImagesInFeedReaders. :)

Comment: @toscho: You mean online feed readers, right? Hmm, yes. But you probably want your visitors to go the actual page, anyway, as a webmaster.

Comment: Yes, I mean online readers. As an author I want my readers to stay subscribed to my feed. Serving content that looks broken will not help. They have probably a good reason to use their software.